# How to run mysql in AWS ssh environment (django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh

1.I can run server in local.

2.I can access aws mysql in local as well.

[image]

3.but if I run server in ssh environment, I got error.

[image]

I need to run mysql first I guess, but I don't think I need to install mysql again into ssh environment.

When I try to run mysql, it goes like:
[image]

Does this mean.... I got a wrong password? but truly it's valid password for aws mysql(I use this password to access local aws mysql)

Comment: You must be root to start mysql service.

Comment: @Marcin I did `su -` to be root, but didn't work : `Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.` . or is there any other method?

Comment: Well its not found. Maybe you failed to install it, your mysql service has different name.

Answer (score 0):

1.select user,host from mysql.user;

2.check system and AWS firewalld port 3306

Comment: Can you let me know what do you mean by 2? I installed firewalld but didn't work too..